Robot Listener, listener v2 on keyword fail status generates a lot of screenshots instead of one
I used Robot Framework listener V2 to catch the current and capture screen shot if the status of the current keyword is FAIL.
So my code is something like this
class RobotListenerV2:
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = "GLOBAL"    
    def end_keyword(self, name, attrs):
        # print('-------------------------------------------------------')
        # print('END keyword NAME => {} and ATTRIBUTES => {}'.format(name, attrs))
        #print('END keyword NAME => {} and ATTRIBUTES => {}'.format(name, attrs['status']))
        # print('-------------------------------------------------------')

        if attrs['status'] == 'FAIL' and attrs['status'] != 'NOT RUN':
            current_directory = os.getcwd()
            try:
                image_folder = ''
                variables = BuiltIn().get_variables()
                for k, v in variables.items():
                    if 'OUTPUT_DIR' in k:
                        image_folder = v
                time_ = round(time.time() * 1000)
                if ' ' in image_folder:
                    image_folder = image_folder.replace(' ','')
                if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(current_directory, image_folder)):
                     os.makedirs(os.path.join(current_directory, image_folder))
                image_name = self.full_screen(image_folder)
                url = self.get_web_driver_instance().current_url

                data_uri = base64.b64encode(open(image_name, 'rb').read()).decode('utf-8')
                logger.info(
                    '<tr><td colspan="3">'
                    '<a '
                    f'href="data:image/png;base64,{data_uri}">'
                    '<img '
                    f'src="data:image/png;base64,{data_uri}" width="{800}px">'
                    '</a></td></tr>',
                    html=True,
                )
                logger.info('<td class="message"><a href="{}">"{}"</a></td>'.format(url, url), html=True)
                logger.info('<td class="message">Keyword Name : {} and attributes : {}</td>'.format(name, attrs), html=True)
            except Exception as ex:
                print("We have Exception:", type(ex))
                print("We have Exception:", repr(ex))
                if hasattr(ex, 'message'):
                    print(ex.message)
                else:
                    print(ex)
            finally:
            

What I found is that Robot Framework takes a lot of screenshot starting from the current keyword until his parent keyword. But what I want is only one screenshot for the current keyword.
Any Idea on how to restrict taking screenshot for the only failing keyword?
If you need an extra details I will put a complete example
